# How to select column in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, datatable, grid, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I an using Ag-Grid.

I want to select column horizontal and vertical like under picture.

How to solution??

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you would have to do this manually. You could watch for cell selection yourself, and then keep track of the selected column. Then you could use `cellStyle` in the column definition params to set the background color when the column is selected. You have to redraw the rows, since the `cellStyle` function only gets run when the rows are drawn. For example:

```
onCellFocused: function(params) {
    if (params.column) {
        selectedColumn = params.column.colDef;
        params.api.redrawRows();
    }
},
defaultColDef: {
    cellStyle: function(params) {
        if (params.colDef === selectedColumn) {
            return {'background-color': '#b7e4ff'};
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it looks like redrawing the rows clears the selection, so you either have to reselect the row manually, or use a row style.

Check it out here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-select-column?embed=1&file=index.js